# regex to clean whitespace BUT "selective"

Tags: php, regex

I am not a great regex specialist, but I know here are some ...

Here's the challenge:

1.) Use-Case:
I want to convert strings into arrays using the PHP function parse_str().

To help make "input" better readeable, I want to allow for spaces, tabs and newlines (whitespaces) wherever posible. That shall be "cleaned" out, if NOT in a value or in a key-name.

As whitespaces should be allowed in the data itself (and maybe WITHIN keys), I cannot just strip all whitespaces before parse_str() ...

Of course I could iterate the array after parse_str and use trim() for the keys and values, but I hope that a preg_replace would do that more efficient (and therefor faster)?

2.) Search:
Now, I search for a regex (to be used in PHP's preg_replace ) that eliminates:
2a.) all whitespace between the last non-whitespace char and the "&" which defines "next pair"
2b.) all whitespaces between "&" and the next non-whitespace char
2c.) all whitespace before and after "="

Is that possible? And: Did I overlook something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *Did I overlook something?* - Sample inputs, expected outputs, and what you have tried and what is not working.

Comment: We are not here to solve problems or write code for people. What have you tried so far, and what exactly do you need help with?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Actually that's exactly why I'm here. That, however, doesn't mean that I/we don't need the info you and Wiktor asks for ;)

Comment: Really, it can be `\s*(=)\s*|(\S)\s+(&)|(&)\s+(\S)` -> `$1$2$3$4$5`, or `\s*(=)\s*|(?<=\S)\s+(?=&)|(?<=&)\s+(?=\S)` -> `$1`, etc... We do not have the data, only you have it, and until we can test our suggestions, your question is just unclear.

Comment: ok. sorry I did not add examples, thought that my question was clear enough.

Some examples:

A_B_C = tx  charfollowed     &G=   charfollowed  &  U=xyz    &O=rrr
shall go into:
A_B_C = tx  charfollowed&G=   charfollowed&U=xyz&O=rrr